# Return with aggregate initialization without type name

Tags: c++, c++20

In C++ 20, for a type like this:

```cpp
struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;
};
```

We can return it from a function using aggregate initialization, with or without writing out the type name:

```cpp
Person getJohn()
{
  // With type name
  return Person {
    .name = "John",
    .age = 42,
  };

  // Without type name
  return {
    .name = "John",
    .age = 42,
  };
}
```

What's the difference between specifying and not specifying the type name explicitly? One thing I noticed is that without a type name, if I mess up the field names/order, the error message given by my compiler and IDE is less clear than if I have a type name. But other than that, are the two forms semantically different in any way?

Comment: Not terribly useful any more, but in C++11 and 14, returning without a type name this way was the only way to get the effect of C++17's "guaranteed copy elision" (i.e. the only way to return a non-movable type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should always be equivalent. A `return` statement performs copy-initialization ([[stmt.return]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2)). A copy-initialization from a *designated-initializer-list* performs aggregate initialization ([[dcl.init.list]/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-3.1)). If the operand is simply the *designated-initializer-list* itself, we are done. The return object has been aggregate-initialized. If the operand is `Person` *designated-initializer-list*, then guaranteed copy elision applies ([[dcl.init.general]/16.6.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.6.1)) which again means that the return object is simply aggregate-initialized (there is no additional temporary object).

Omitting the type can only make a difference in non-aggregate-initialization contexts: if the user-defined constructor selected for the initialization has been declared `explicit`, the program is ill-formed. But aggregate initialization doesn't use a constructor.